# Azure build fails after Git push

Tags: azure, msbuild, web-deployment

I have a web site setup in azure, which is configured to do deployments after I commit code to Git. Synchronization part works fine, as Azure is able to auto-detect pushes to Git and starts a build.

However, build fails with following error message:

> EastVisionSystems.Util -> C:\DWASFiles\Sites\TheCastOd\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Platform\project\EastVisionSystems.Util\bin\Release\EastVisionSystems.Util.dll
>
> SGEN : error : An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\TheCastOd\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Platform\project\PaypalPaymentModule\PaypalPaymentModule.csproj]

Needless to say that solutions builds just fine on local machine. I can even deploy from Visual Studio to Azure and site runs OK.

I'm using VS 2010 Ultimate and targeting .NET 4.0. Configuration Manager is setup for "Any CPU".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issues per Microsoft. Should be fixed in 4-6 weeks.
[Posted same question at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuregit/thread/23f2177e-5071-4d75-8646-0f624dfd9bc7)